# Jquery search text heighlighting issue

Tags: jquery, html, search

just open the fiddle and type 'rima' in search box then press down arrow, here all li tags are selecting but it should select where searched term is equals to li text.

This is my     **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/nelsonfeel/420Lf338/1/)** and code.

**Jquery**

```
var $expandBtns = $('.expandBtn');
var $span;

//Search    
$('input#catInput').keyup(function(e) {
  var searchTerms = $(this).val();
  console.log('Input change');
  if (searchTerms == '') {
    $expandBtns.each(function() {
      var $subList = $(this).siblings('ul');
      $subList.hide('slow');
    });
  }
  $('#orgCat li').each(function() {
    var $li = $(this);
    var hasMatch = searchTerms.length == 0 || $li.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerms.toLowerCase()) > 0;
    $li.toggle(hasMatch).removeClass('searchActiveLi');

    if ($li.is(':hidden')) {
      $li.closest('ul').show('slow');
    }

    if(e.keyCode == 40 && searchTerms.length !=0){ //highlighting selected li using down arrow key
        $li.addClass('searchActiveLi');
    }    
  });
```

Above code is which I used in my Fiddle any queries please ask me in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here that `$li.text()` will return the content between `<li></li>` even if there is an `<ul></ul>` inside.

**Example**

```
<ul id="outerUl">
  <li id="test">
   <ul>
    <li> foo </li>
    <li> bar </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
 $('#test').text(); //<== This will out put : foo bar
 //So, if i do $('#test').text().toLowerCase().indexOf("foo") it will return a real index of "foo" !
```

So what you have to do is to check if the last child conatines the word that you are looking for :

```
if(e.keyCode == 40 && searchTerms.length !=0){ //highlighting selected li using down arrow key
    if($li.children('ul').length <= 0) //<== If the li does not contain any other list
        $li.addClass('searchActiveLi');
}
```

Here is your updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/420Lf338/12/)

**UPDATE :**

I found a way to highlight the `li` with the matched text and put it's content in the search box :

```
if(e.keyCode == 40 && searchTerms.length !=0 && matched.length > 0){ //highlighting selected li using down arrow key
 if(arrowDownClick < matched.length){
    if(arrowDownClick > 0)
    matched[arrowDownClick - 1].removeClass('searchActiveLi');
    var $selectedli = matched[arrowDownClick];
  $selectedli.addClass('searchActiveLi');
  var selectedliText = $selectedli.text();
  $('input#catInput').val(selectedliText);
  arrowDownClick++;
 }else{
    matched[arrowDownClick - 1].removeClass('searchActiveLi');
    arrowDownClick = 0;
 }
}
```

To do so, I used an array `matched` to store the matched `li` every time the value of the search box change. But when the user clicks on the `down arrow`, The script process the table of the matched `li` and remove the class `.searchActiveLi` from the selected `li` and add it to the next one.

Here is the final [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/420Lf338/18/), please tell me if you need any further explanation.

Comment: Thank you @Hamza Abdaoui, It's working but once type 'ri' and check it is selecing all children. It should select individually it means add class where li is selected

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nelsonfeel/420Lf338/16/ check this all names are displaying in search box.

Comment: @nani0077, i did not understand what's required! do you want to add the class to only the first `li` and then if I press the down arrow again it selects the next `li` ?

Comment: Yes exactly, remove class to first li, update search box with selected li text this is my requirement

Comment: I hope you understand my problem.

Comment: You mean ; when the arrow down is pressed, the first `li` with the matched terms should be highlighted and it's content should be placed in the search box ? And so on if i presse the down arrow again ..

Comment: Yes @Hamza Abdaoui exactly. you understood my point please help me

Comment: @nani0077 I updated my answer and the fiddle, take a look.

Comment: if you don't mind Please check this https://jsfiddle.net/420Lf338/20/ its looking like simple. their is an ssue type 'str' in search box and check

Comment: Hi @Hamza Abdaoui, up and down arrow issue in yesterday' s work check this https://jsfiddle.net/420Lf338/24/

Comment: Issue: when i press up arrow it moving to only one step back

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151051/discussion-between-hamza-abdaoui-and-nani0077).

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
$li.addClass('searchActiveLi');
```

USE

```
 $li.each(function(){
    if($(this).find('li').length  <= 1){
     $li.addClass('searchActiveLi');
    }
   })
```

Comment: It's working and selecting group of li  but it should select one li only